# How to take N groups from pandas dataframe when grouped by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am having this kind of code (code sample is recreation of production code) -

```
import pandas as pd
df_nba = pd.read_csv('https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/nba.csv')
df_nba['custom'] = 'abc'
df_gpby_team_clg = df_nba.groupby(['custom', 'College', 'Team']).agg({'Salary': sum})
print(df_gpby_team_clg)
```

Output looks something like this -

[image]

Now I want to have first `N` `College` stats. So if I give `n=2` I will have a `df` with `Alabama` and `Arizona` and their respective `Team` and `Salary` stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to restore the dataframe after `groupby()` with multi-index row index back to normal range index for easier subsequent operations.

Then extract the first n colleges into a list by calling [`.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) on the `College` column.

Finally, filter the expanded dataframe with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by checking for `College` is in the first n colleges just extracted by using [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) within [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
n = 2
df_gpby_team_clg_expand = df_gpby_team_clg.reset_index()
first_N_college = df_gpby_team_clg_expand['College'].unique()[:n]

df_gpby_team_clg_expand.loc[df_gpby_team_clg_expand['College'].isin(first_N_college)]
```

Result:

```
   custom  College                   Team      Salary
0     abc  Alabama    Cleveland Cavaliers   2100000.0
1     abc  Alabama      Memphis Grizzlies    845059.0
2     abc  Alabama   New Orleans Pelicans   1320000.0
3     abc  Arizona          Brooklyn Nets   1335480.0
4     abc  Arizona    Cleveland Cavaliers   9140305.0
5     abc  Arizona        Detroit Pistons   2841960.0
6     abc  Arizona  Golden State Warriors  11710456.0
7     abc  Arizona        Houston Rockets    947276.0
8     abc  Arizona         Indiana Pacers   5358880.0
9     abc  Arizona        Milwaukee Bucks   3000000.0
10    abc  Arizona        New York Knicks   4000000.0
11    abc  Arizona          Orlando Magic   4171680.0
12    abc  Arizona     Philadelphia 76ers    525093.0
13    abc  Arizona           Phoenix Suns    206192.0
```